# codeigniter email function

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, sendmail

i am trying to send a email with the following code in controller class in codeigniter framework...

```
    $config['protocol'] = 'sendmail'; 
    $config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail'; 

    $this->load->library('email', $config); 

    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n"); 

    $this->email->from('tanvir@soft-bd.com', 'tanvir@soft-bd.com'); 
    $this->email->to('tanvir064@gmail.com');         
    $this->email->subject('This is an email test');         
    $this->email->message('It is working. Great!'); 

    if ($this->email->send()) { 
        echo "Sent!"; 
        $this->email->print_debugger(); 

    } else { 
        echo "FAILED"; 
        echo $this->email->print_debugger(); 
    }
```

but following error are showing

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: can u show the config array fully i mean smtp_host, port etc......

Comment: FAILEDThe following SMTP error was encountered: 110 Connection timed out
Unable to send data: AUTH LOGIN
Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error:
Unable to send data: MAIL FROM:

from: 

The following SMTP error was encountered:
Unable to send data: RCPT TO:

to: 

The following SMTP error was encountered:
Unable to send data: DATA

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code. I am sending mails from Gmail smtp server......

```
function sendMail()
    {
        $config = Array(
      'protocol' => 'smtp',
      'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
      'smtp_port' => 465,
      'smtp_user' => 'xxx@gmail.com', // change it to yours
      'smtp_pass' => 'xxx', // change it to yours
      'mailtype' => 'html',
      'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
      'wordwrap' => TRUE
    );

            $message = $this->load->view('upload_success','',TRUE);
            $this->load->library('email', $config);
          $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
          $this->email->from('xxx@gmail.com'); // change it to yours
          $this->email->to('yyy@gmail.com');// change it to yours
          $this->email->subject('Resume from JobsBuddy for your Job posting');
          $this->email->message($message);
          if($this->email->send())
         {
          echo 'Email sent.';
         }
         else
        {
         show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
        }

    }
```

Comment: smtp_user is my mail id and smtp_pass is my mail password, right?

Comment: yeah obviously and i am loading a view as my message you need to replace it with your message

Answer (score 0):

Paste this code in starting of your function

```
$this->load->library('email');
$config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
$config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$this->email->initialize($config);
```

This may help to you!

Comment: Usually calling initialize() or passing the $config to the loader are the same thing

Comment: thnx....when i am using tanvir@soft-bd.com for sending email then it's ok, but using tanvir064@gmail.com then it's not working. actually it's not working for gmail,hotmail and others..